# modify csv with php before import / upload with php

Tags: php, mysql, database, csv

I want to upload a csv to a database with php, but before i do that i want to modify some of the content.

The database table the csv will come from has 3 columns: id, postcode, debt_amount
The database table the csv will go to has 4 columns: id, postcode, debt_amount, count

What  i want to do first is modify the full postcode to just show the first part before the 'space'.
Then i want to consolidate all the rows that have the same modified postcode, this will do two things:

1. Count the number of rows with the same modified postcode and place the total number into the consolidated row in the column 'count'.
2. Add up the 'debt_amount' column for the same modified postcode and put the total amount into the consolidated row under the 'debt_amount' column.

These processes would need to run together.
After that is done i want to upload it to the database.

I don't know if this is the best way of doing it, or if i should process the data from the first database first and export it into a CSV, to just allow me to upload the CSV on the other database.
Any help on either process would be good.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is best to process this data in MySQL itself. You may decide if you would like to process it in the source database or the target database.

So, if the processing involves:

- modify the postcode
- count #rows with same modified-postcode
- sum debt_amount for same modified-postcode

Either do the processing in the source database, store the results in a temporary table, generate the CSV and then import to the target database. Or generate the CSV from the source DB, import to the target database in a temporary table, do the processing and store the results to the final table.

Comment: Thanks Abhay, i like this way, i think handling on the new database location will be easier. Could you provide some code that could help do these processes, counting the rows with the same postcode and passing that to the new table and adding the debt_amount for this postcode?

Comment: @zizther, sure. We can try to work out using the query that you've got. Do you have a query that you've tried?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have no query yet, as it was just me thinking of how i could handle the data. If it does come up again, i'll comment back.

Thanks

Comment: No problem @zizther, you are always welcome on SO. If you think, my answer helped you, will you please mind accepting it? :-)

Answer (score 0):

1. Do the standard file upload.
2. Read the CSV content from the temporary upload file.
3. Process the CSV Data (e.g. with [`SplFileObject`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/SplFileObject).
4. Insert the processed data into your database.